# constructor cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java

Есть такая ошибка. В гугле нормального объяснения не нашел, возможно плохо читал...

```
java: constructor ChatErrors in class tire.lightchat.errorfinder.ChatErrors cannot be applied to given types;
  required: tire.lightchat.main.LightChat
  found:    no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Класс `ChatErrors`:

```java
    private LightChat plugin;
    public ChatErrors(LightChat plugin) { this.plugin = plugin; }

    public void onEnableCheck() {
      // ...
    }
```

Перед ним стоит

```java
import tire.lightchat.main.LightChat;
```

Вызываю этот класс в:

```java
import tire.lightchat.errorfinder.ChatErrors;
public final class LightChat extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
      // ...
      ChatErrors errors = new ChatErrors();
      errors.onEnableCheck();
    }
}
```

Как исправить?

Comment: ну а где тут что-то передаётся в конструктор ChatErrors?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а это обязательно? если мне, например, ничего не нужно туда передавать?

Comment: Ну тогда надо в конструкторе сделать его необязательным

Comment: @а, стоп, максимально глупый был вопрос. я this забыл передать, да, нужно передавать, спасибо, что указали на ошибку))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я `this` забыл передать...

```java
ChatErrors errors = new ChatErrors(this);
errors.onEnableCheck();
```